# Having trouble with class constructors printing

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

I'm trying to learn how classes and their constructors work by creating a Time class that includes an hour, minute, and second. I wanted to print one time by using the default constructor and one through user input. While my program compiles, it does not ask for user input, most likely because of the way I call the class function getHour (if I were to only print the input hour). I am also unsure of how to print the time (0,0,0) through the default constructor.

Any help would be appreciated!

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"

int main(){

    std::cout << "Enter the hour, minute, and second: " << std::endl;
    int hour, minute, second;
    std::cin >> hour >> minute >> second;

    Time time1(hour, minute, second);

    std::cout << time1.getHour() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Class implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"

//default constructor
Time::Time() {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
}

//construct from hour, minute, second
Time::Time(int theHour, int theMinute, int theSecond) {
    hour = theHour;
    minute = theMinute;
    second = theSecond;
}

int Time::getHour() const {
    return hour;
}

int Time::getMinute() const {
    return minute;
}

int Time::getSecond() const {
    return second;
}
```

Comment: ***it does not ask for user input, most likely because of the way I call the class function getHour (if I were to only print the input hour)*** Are you sure you are running a build of the current code? The input is in `main()` and has nothing to do with `getHour()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me, this was my output:

```
Enter the hour, minute, and second:
2
45
32
2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Make sure you are rebuilding the code and running the new executable.

In the constructor you can just do:

```
Time::Time() {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;

    std::cout << hour << " " << minute << " " << second << std::endl;
}
```

this will be called anytime you call Time with the default constructor:

```
    std::cout << "Enter the hour, minute, and second: " << std::endl;
    int hour, minute, second;
    std::cin >> hour >> minute >> second;

    Time t; //<--- this prints 0,0,0
    Time time1(hour, minute, second);

    std::cout << time1.getHour() << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

will result in:

```
Enter the hour, minute, and second:
11
19
59
0 0 0
11
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am also unsure of how to print the time (0,0,0) through the default constructor.

Unless I missing something subtle,

```
// Construct a Time object using the default constructor.
Time time2;

// Print it's hour
std::cout << time2.getHour() << std::endl;
```

Comment: I think it the question is this + running an old executable.

Comment: While this compiles, it still does not print anything.

Comment: @Mariankka, what's your programming environment? How are you running the program?

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared doesn't try to print an object constructed with the default constructor since `getHour()` is called by `time1`. The is doing what you tell it to do. If you want the full time from `time1`you'll have to call all of the getters eg: `std::cout << time1.getHour() << " : " << time1.getMinute() << " : " << time1.getSecond() << std::endl`

Answer (score 0):

***"I am also unsure of how to print the time (0,0,0) through the default constructor."***

consider a `displayTime()` method that can be called on to display the time of any instance

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    std::cout << "Enter the hour, minute, and second: " << std::endl;
    int hour, minute, second;
    std::cin >> hour >> minute >> second;

    Time time1(hour, minute, second);         // overloaded constructor
    Time time2;                               // default constructor

//  std::cout << time1.getHour() << std::endl;
//  std::cout << time2.getHour() << std::endl;

    time1.displayTime();
    time2.displayTime();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

add displayTime() method

```
void Time::displayTime() const{
std::cout << this->hour << ","
          << this->minute << ","
          << this->second << std::endl;
}
```